# Why won't my DLL register with RegSvr32?

Tags: dll, winapi, regsvr32

I have to register a .dll file named `MatchMolDLL.dll`.

To register the DLL I followed these steps:

1) Goto RUN
2) Type “cmd”
3) Type “regsvr32 MatchMolDLL.dll”

However `regsvr32.exe` reports:

> "MatchMolDLL.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found."

How can I register it?

If I had to link this .dll file with another executable can it be done?

Comment: How is this related to PHP?  (Is it a module or something?)

Comment: Is it a native .dll or a .NET assembly?

Answer (score 1):

`MatchMoIDLL.dll` isn't a COM DLL and you can't use `regsvr32.exe` to register it. It's a plain old Win32 DLL.

You can find out more about it here:

> http://merian.pch.univie.ac.at/~nhaider/cheminf/cmmm.html#dll

Answer (score 1):

It is not a COM server.  You have to use P/Invoke to use this DLL.  The instructions are available in the [source code file](http://merian.pch.univie.ac.at/pch/download/chemistry/checkmol/dll/MATCHMOLDLL.pas), it gives the VB6 declarations:

```
Private Declare Sub mm_SetMol Lib "matchmolDLL.dll" (ByVal st As String)
Private Declare Sub mm_SetCurrentMolAsQuery Lib "matchmolDLL.dll" ()
Private Declare Function mm_Match Lib "matchmolDLL.dll" (ByVal Exact As Boolean) As Long

Private Declare Function mm_GetRings Lib "matchmolDLL.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function mm_GetAtomRing Lib "matchmolDLL.dll" (ByVal AtomNumber As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub mm_Version Lib "matchmolDLL.dll" (ByVal st As String)
```

Which you'll have to translate to the corresponding VB.NET or C# [DllImport] declaration.  Use "int" instead of Long in those declarations.  For example:

```
[DllImport("matchmolDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern void mm_SetMol(string st);
```

Etcetera.

Comment: Nice answer. I was going to do the same but nodded off after a night of code at 7am this morning. +1